# How do I completely uninstall Google Chrome and Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, uninstall, chromium

I'm having a problem with Chrome and one of its extensions, so I want to completely uninstall everything. I've uninstalled Chrome through the Software Center, but when I reinstall it, all of my extensions and preferences are still there.

If I want to start over from scratch, what do I need to do?

Comment: I'm going to make this into a more general question, since the directions here will cover both Chromium and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**For Google Chrome:**

Deleting `~/.config/google-chrome` (where `~` is your home directory) should be sufficient. Why don't you try it and see? (Of course, this will delete all your bookmarks too.)

If that's not sufficient, you may want to also remove Google Chrome from the Terminal using the `sudo apt-get purge ...` command (where `...` is replaced by the package you want to remove or a space-separated list of the packages you want to remove), or remove it in the Synaptic Package Manager (which you can install in the Software Center if you don't have it; it's itself provided by the package `synaptic`) by right-clicking on the packages you want to remove and clicking "Mark for Complete Removal". These ways of removing packages will remove all global (i.e., non-user-specific) configuration files.

**For Chromium** (the completely open source counterpart to Chrome)**:**

You can do it the same way, just delete `~/.config/chromium`. You can also remove the package as mentioned above for Google Chrome. The package that provides Chromium in Ubuntu is called `chromium-browser`.

Comment: Bookmarks are saved in XMarks, so not an issue. I'll try deleting the folder and see if that helps. If not, I'll try the other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: how do I remove Chrome from the terminal using apt-get purge .... ?

Comment: You can find where the Chrome file is using `which google-chrome` and deleting it there. It should be in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: this answer is incomplete because it doesnt note that chrome is called google-chrome-stable under apt-get.

Answer (score 100):

**Note**: this recipe has been updated in

- 2023 to include instructions for Snap-based installations
- 2020 to more safely backup the files rather than using a recursive delete

### Snap-based installation (Ubuntu 22.04+)

Uninstalling the Chromium Snap is relatively straightforward:

```
sudo snap remove chromium
```

### APT-based installation (< Ubuntu 22.04)

To uninstall **Chromium Browser**, run these commands from your terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
$ mv ~/.config/chromium/ ~/.config/chromium.bak/
```

To uninstall **Google Chrome**, run these commands from your terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
$ mv ~/.config/google-chrome/ ~/.config/google-chrome.bak/
```

In both examples, the first command removes the package, while the second command will move custom settings, such as plugins, to a backup directory.

Comment: Successfully uninstall 'Google Chrome' stable.

Comment: Don't forget there are also files in `~/.cache/google-chrome/` and `~/.config/google-chrome/`. And there are variants of Google chrome like `google-chrome-beta` and `google-chrome-stable`. If in doubt you can check you've got everything by running `locate google-chrome`. locate is a local search tool that can be installed with `sudo apt install locate`

Comment: For me, `locate google-chrome` returned a lot of files that had already been deleted.  If anyone faces the same problem, run `sudo updatedb` to update mlocate database. (`locate` searches for entries in mlocate database)

Comment: This may have been correct at the time, but as of Ubuntu 22.04 you must "sudo snap remove chromium".  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401800/how-to-remove-chromium-from-snap .

Answer (score 12):

I successfully removed Google Chrome by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: You'll also want to remove /etc/apt/sources.d/google.list and its public keys that got added to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.

Comment: No need to write '-get' in Ubuntu version 18.04 or greater