# How do I remove Chromium including its settings?

Tags: 11.10, uninstall, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I completely uninstall Google Chrome and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium)

How do I remove the settings from Chromium program in Ubuntu 11.10? Yesterday I tried to remove from synaptic by choosing pull out its configuration. but when i try to install again from USC, the application appears as when last I used yesterday. It means that the application has not fully been removed. Is there a clean way to remove these applications?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [How do I completely uninstall Google Chrome and Chromium?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove an application and all of its configuration files you'll need to purge it. Open up a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 10):

To remove the package, run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
```

Then to remove all the data created by chromium (cache, personal configuration, etc...), run:

```
rm -fr ~/.cache/chromium
rm -fr ~/.config/chromium
```