# How to remove chromium-browser settings from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium, browser

I have already gone through 
[How do I completely uninstall Google Chrome and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium) and I'm really not getting why the solutions given there are not working for me.

What I'm doing is:

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser  
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
```

Then reinstalling by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

This must remove the settings of chromium-browser and do a fresh installation.
The browser is uninstalling, but after being installed it is containing the previous settings, moreover it's not signing me out of even Gmail!

Comment: I have edited my previous answer, also remove ~/.cache/chromium and /etc/chromium.Check it and if it works click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "I accept the answer" and upvote

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Execute these commands in terminal  :

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium --purge
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
sudo rm -rf /etc/chromium
```

Comment: @Neel Then why did you accept this answer? Your comment is either false or misleadnig. If the answer didn't solve your problem, please unaccept it, and if it did solve your problem remove your comment which is obsolate.

Comment: @bakuriu the comment is for old answer, which i updated later

Answer (score 15):

You don't need to uninstall/reinstall the browser.

To delete the settings for a given user, you must delete the config folder for that user (placed in its home, as a hidden folder, thus the `.` at the start of the name).

You may delete that folder using the terminal or you may open the home folder in Nautilus and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden files and folders, then delete the folder you want to delete as you would do with any other file.

This prevents you from using `rm -rf` variations in which a small typo can have serious consequences.

Comment: you gave a nice solution. sorry couldn't vote you up as it requires 15 rep. Thanks though!! :)

Comment: No problem @Neel! Welcome to the forums :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sudo apt purge --remove chromium-browser -y
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean -y
```

This removes the chromium browser completely

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu later versions you can uninstall from **Ubuntu Software**

```
snap-store
```

Try `sudo killall snap-store` to reload **Ubuntu Software**