# Trying anything to remove Chrome sources.list error

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, 64-bit

I keep getting the [famous sources.list error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/742402) even after trying to implement the supposed fix.

My next thing is to try to totally remove chrome/chromium and start over.   So I followed [these removal instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/525485/115913).

However, now when I do `apt-get update`, I keep getting the same error.  What triggers the error?  How can I completely remove chrome or whatever triggers that error?

Comment: Are you running 32bit Ubuntu or 64bit? If 32bit I assume you you will uninstall Chrome... Could you show any terminal output for `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"`?

Comment: Oops make that `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Comment: @andrew.46, yes it's 64-bit.   As per the instructions by cl-netbox, the google-chrome.list file no longer exists on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question first - for getting rid of the `sudo apt-get update` error message, you have to remove the Google Chrome repository  - open a terminal and execute this command :

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

To completely remove `Chromium` and `Google Chrome` execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser google-chrome-stable
```

When you also want to remove the configuration files, delete these folders :

`/home/user/.config/chromium` and `/home/user/.config/google-chrome`.

Note : I assume that you have the `google-chrome-stable` package installed.

Update :

I received an [information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170?noredirect=1#comment1128118_724170) that there might be another Google `.list` file in the `sources.list.d` folder - so in case the error still occurs, check this folder and correct or delete the entries as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally thought of looking around in the  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory to see if there was anything other than chrome/chromium in that is associated with google somehow.  Indeed, I found a `google.list` file.  I have no idea how that got there or what program it was associated with, but after deleting it my `apt-get update` worked cleanly.