# Google Chrome signing problem

Tags: google-chrome, sync, 17.10

I am using ubuntu 17.10 and installed chrome. The problem I am facing is, I am not able to sign into chrome to sync my bookmarks and browser history. As soon I click "sign in to chrome"

[image]

The browser freezes like this and closes off.

And when I relaunch chrome it says "restore pages" as chrome didn't shut down properly. 
[image]

The same problem I am facing with chromium. Can anyone help me fix this ? I really need to sync my bookmarks and history. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found my solution. This involves the following steps:

1) Uninstall chrome completely using the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
$ rm ~/.config/google chrome/ -rf
```

I have followed [Oxley's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium) answer for the asked question.

Next install google chrome stable afresh using the following commands and for this I have followed ElefantPhace's answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) question with some modifications.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port http://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

And now, I am able to sync my bookmarks again. Hope this answer helps someone else who is facing similar issues.

Comment: ❤️❤️❤️ Can confirm this still works in 2021, the proxy isn't necessary though.

Comment: @ThomasReggi, my previous internet connectivity in my campus required a proxy username with a port. That is why I added a generic command. Most of them wont require this though.