# Chrome ignores --force-display-scale-factor flag?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, scaling

I faced this humongous Chrome UI problem and stumbled upon [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1116767/chrome-ui-size-zoom-levels-in-ubuntu-16-04)
 question on superuser, which uses the same Ubuntu version. I have followed the accepted answer there but apparently it does not have any effect.
Is there a new workaround for this issue?

My display is not a HiDPI one, it is 1366x768, scaling factor is set at 0.875 in order to make text the same size as in Windows. Every other program follows this scaling, except Chrome.

Comment: did you try chromes settings? settings -->advanced settings --> web content

Comment: No there is no such setting in Chrome.

Comment: yes there is. chrome has it's own scaling factor setting

Comment: Sorry but can you point it to me? Under advanced settings, the submenus are privacy&security, password&form, language, download, printing, accessibility, system, and reset. Where is this web content setting located?

Comment: https://ibb.co/mRCRu5

Comment: I see, in Chrome 60 the settings page is completely different, that part has been renamed and moved, but I have found it nonetheless. BUT, as the setting says it is for WEB content, not for the Chrome UI.

Comment: it changes the scaling on the displayed web page, which fixes the issue in the question you had linked

Comment: I think you completely missed my point, I don't have any issue with the displayed web page, but the Chrome UI, that is, the tabs, bookmark bar, right click menu, overflow menu, etc. It stated there clearly on the first line in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove Chrome completely as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium)
2. Set the system-wide font size to desired value (if it is already the desired value, change it to something else, reboot, then change to the size you want)
3. Reboot
4. Install Chrome again

Chrome will respect the system-wide font size this way. The rebooting might be unnecessary, but it doesn't work for me without rebooting first after changing font.