# Chrome ignoring .desktop flag

Tags: google-chrome, 18.04

Ever since I installed 18.04 and reinstalled google chrome, chrome ignores flags when launched with `google-chrome`. It used to work and I had `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=2 %U` in my .desktop file. However using `google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=2` from terminal does work.

I don't want to change my system-wide font like in [Chrome ignores --force-display-scale-factor flag?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950783/chrome-ignores-force-display-scale-factor-flag) Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need double quotes to make this flag work, i.e. `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome "--force-device-scale-factor=2" %U`.

Also, logout and login again and check whether chrome is properly scaled. In my case, this approach works perfectly fine on Ubuntu 18.04.