# How to remove Ad Malware/Virus from Google Chrome which causes ads to appear in list of results?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Screenshot of Ads appearing as chrome search results:
[image: Screenshot of Ads appearing as chrome search results.]

I don't know what got into my system. I am really fed up with these.

1. I have looked up all my extensions and did not find anything malicious.
2. I deleted Chrome referring to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium) and reinstalled it again but nothing changed.

Please help.

Comment: Do you get different results using a different browser (e.g. Firefox)?

Comment: @danzel  No, I don't. Firefox is working just fine.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all extensions?

Comment: Yes. I disabled all extensions and enabled them one by one. It was due to PDF Mergy extension. I deleted that. It stored back to normal. Thank you for your help.