# Removing remaining packages after having unistalled google-chrome

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, 32-bit

Hereby posting my first question to this brilliant forum!

I had an old, and, due to 32-bit xubuntu system, not longer supported, installation of chrome. The remove command did not, according to output from update (see below)), take everything away, so I tried purge which didn´t change the outcome.

How can I proceed?
Spam-restriction prevented me from supplying full documentation, so I hope instead for help step-by-step [After some editing now with the intended documentation].

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Ign:1 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Get:5 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]             
Get:6 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]         
Get:7 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Ign:8 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease                      
Err:9 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Ign:6 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
E: The repository 'http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'google-chrome-stable' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-chrome-stable*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 238783 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for google-chrome-stable (48.0.2564.116-1) ...
```

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                  
Ign:3 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                        
Hit:4 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease                                     
Get:5 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                   
Hit:6 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                       
Get:7 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]                                         
Get:8 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]              
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
E: The repository 'http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
```

Thank you!

**Edit:**
Tried commands as mentioned in the answer. Note the two updates in sequence that for some reason gave slightly different output.

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for peter: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                               
Hit:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                             
Hit:4 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease                                        
Ign:5 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Get:6 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]                               
Get:7 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]     
Get:8 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]        
Ign:7 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg 
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
E: The repository 'http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 

peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                              
Ign:3 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                    
Hit:4 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                            
Get:5 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]                                                                                                              
Get:6 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]                                                                                    
Get:7 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Ign:8 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease                            
Err:9 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy Release                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Ign :6 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
E: The repository 'http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**Edit:**
Result from using `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>`

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.peImdN0Ry6/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 17 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: public key "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Get:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB] 
Ign:4 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:5 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]             
Get:6 http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]         
Hit:7 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease       
Ign:8 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease               
Err:9 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'google-chrome-stable' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$
```

**Edit:**
Result after, by using the GUI "Software & Updates", having removed one software with crome in it, and one with saucy.

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Get:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Get:4 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Hit:5 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease
Fetched 163 kB in 2s (71,9 kB/s)                                                                
Reading package lists... Done
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$
```

Edit: As suggested by karel, I commented out the following line in source.list: `#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner`. Now only four items remains to be addressed.

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                 
Hit:2 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                         
Get:3 http ://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Get:4 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Fetched 163 kB in 4s (43,1 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$
```

Edit: Trying to solve the problem by change in sources.list in accordance to advice given by karel.

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#Five lines inserted 04/25/2019 #P = commented out same day
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
#P deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
#P deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
#P deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
#P deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
#P deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
#P deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
#P deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
#P deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
#P deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
#P deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
#P deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
#P deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
#P deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main universe multiverse restricted
#P deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main universe multiverse restricted

#P deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
#P deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
#P deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
#P deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
#P deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
#P deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial mainGXGXG
```

[image]

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                           
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                   
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Fetched 163 kB in 2s (84,5 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: @karel Thanks, sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY> got rid of the GPG error. See new output from update in my question. Hoping for further assistance!

Comment: You're using 18.04 bionic but you still have repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` from 13.10 saucy that are interfering with package management. Those lines with saucy in them should be commented out by starting them with a `#` character. Afterwards run `sudo apt update` to refresh the package lists.

Comment: @karel Thanks again, The list is shrinking by and by. When trying to access the list in the terminal I got: peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied, so I used the GUI instead.

Comment: `Hit:5 http ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy InRelease` shows that there is still one more line with saucy in it that needs to be commented out.

Comment: @karel Using nano (sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list) I now have commented out one line with saucy in it. New result from update is edited into my question. Many thanks!

Comment: @karel The source.list is now edited to just the standard as the one you linked to. New output can be seen in the question. Also the lines that I commented out is marked P. Maybe I must uncomment some lines again to get it right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore default apt repositories in sources.list from command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/586595)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get autoclean 

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

These two commands clean old and unused packages

Comment: Thanks, tried both the commands you suggested. However, in my case, it seems not much happend. Find output in my question. Was to long to fit into comment-space.

Comment: Here's another link that may help out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium