# How to remove Chromium from snap?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, snap, chromium, 21.04

I'm looking to remove `chromium` as so:

```
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# snap info chromium
name:      chromium
summary:   Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/chromium
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   unset
description: |
  An open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more
  stable way for all Internet users to experience the web.
commands:
  - chromium.chromedriver
  - chromium
snap-id:      XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 3 days ago, at 22:33 PDT
channels:
  latest/stable:    100.0.4896.75 2022-04-07 (1957) 137MB -
  latest/candidate: 100.0.4896.75 2022-04-06 (1957) 137MB -
  latest/beta:      101.0.4951.15 2022-04-01 (1952) 139MB -
  latest/edge:      101.0.4951.15 2022-03-31 (1952) 139MB -
installed:          100.0.4896.75            (1957) 137MB -
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-49-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 17:36:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# sudo snap remove chromium
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Save data of snap "chromium" in automatic snapshot set #9 (cannot create archive:
tar: common/chromium: file changed as we read it)
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
root@mordor:~#
```

but am stuck in the above loop.

Comment: Hello. Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) End of Life reached on January 20 2022. It is off topic on this site. Sorry.

Comment: Try `snap remove --purge chromium`, which should skip that backup (`save data`) step. However, skipping the backup will delete all Chromium-related data like your profile and history. @David is right: You should catch up to a supported release of Ubuntu for several very good reasons.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: the solution from @user535733 worked:  `snap remove --purge chromium` and I'd expect that work for most any version.  Considered asked and answered.  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to purge the snap package, but be aware it will delete all configuration and your personal settings including you bookmarks and stored data. So I suggest you take a backup first of your profile.

Then as already mentioned in the comments:

```
sudo snap remove --purge chromium
```