# Chromium not uninstalled properly on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, chromium

I have installed chromium on ubuntu 22.04, but it didn't work properly, I got the following errors
`chrome failed to start: /system.slice/test.service is not a snap cgroup,`

then I uninstalled chromium from ubuntu and delete all files regarding it, with the following commands -

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove chromium-browser
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
sudo rm -rf /snap/bin/chromium
```

Now I installed chrome but now I am getting same error
`chrome failed to start: /system.slice/test.service is not a snap cgroup,`

Can you please help me figure out the reason and how to solve this?

Comment: did you install Chromium as a Snap? In terminal type `which chromium`. If it was installed as a Snap, you need a different command to uninstall it - see [this Ask Ubuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401800/how-to-remove-chromium-from-snap)

Comment: @graham No, I have installed chromium using `sudo apt install chromium-browser`. After using the `sudo rm -rf /snap/bin/chromium` after sometime when I checked `which chromium` the path i got again was /snap/bin/chromium, Can you please tell us which command I can use to uninstall chromium. So, that the above error get resolved

Comment: "please tell us which command I can use to uninstall chromium" Its in the linked Q&A I provided - `sudo snap remove --purge chromium`

Comment: But I haven't used snap for installing chromium

Comment: "/snap/bin/chromium" clearly indicates that you have the Chromium version installed. There is no deb version available in the repositories only Snap. In terminal type  `snap list chromium` to confirm Then use `sudo snap remove --purge chromium` to remove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Chromium from snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401800/how-to-remove-chromium-from-snap)

Comment: The above command removed chromium but I haven't use snap for installing chromium but any how this worked for me, Thank you @graham

Comment: When you use Ubuntu Software you will see that it will indicate on the top bar the Source of the app to install in a drop down menu from which you can select your choice - either deb or Snap version. You seemingly chose the first option without realising the significance of the options available (although in the case of Chromium, only Snap versions are available with `latest/stable` being the first one offered). Great that you now have it sorted.