# Google chrome white screen

Tags: google-chrome, screen, ubuntu-gnome

Getting white screen on google chrome, chrome beta and Firefox are working fine. Have tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome. Unable to access chrome settings, same issue, the letters are not coming up at all. White boxes are visible though. Kindly assist on this.

Comment: Is your Chrome in dark mode? If it is, then I can give you a solution(really tricky though).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. It has something to do with hardware acceleration. To access the settings and turn off hardware acceleration, you can open Chrome in Incognito mode. You will then be able to access settings, search for hardware acceleration and toggle it off. Then you can reopen Chrome in normal mode and it will work again. I wanted hardware acceleration in any case, so I tried enabling again, and I had the same problem. Then I tried repeating the same process, logging in and logging out, enabling, disabling and enabling again, and after a few tries, it worked. Not sure why, but it is hardware acceleration causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, but in Ubuntu 22.04. For me, the UI of every website looked very weird. I turned off the hardware acceleration and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the steps. Earlier i did not uninstall chrome completely. Uninstalled chrome completely and reinstalled the same, it worked.

Followed below steps to uninstall chrome:

sudo dpkg -r google-chrome-stable
 sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
removed .config/google-chrome
sudo apt-get update and upgrade

Ref: [How do I completely uninstall Google Chrome and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium)

Unfortunately, i did not get the chance to view and edit the settings from incognito mode. Better luck next time.

Thanks everyone for the help!